# Не могу правильно обработать foreach

Tags: php, foreach

Есть вот такой массив:

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [category] => Website
                    [name] => Brains
                    [id] => 2791308653434598
                    [perms] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => ADMINISTER
                            [1] => EDIT_PROFILE
                            [2] => CREATE_CONTENT
                            [3] => MODERATE_CONTENT
                            [4] => CREATE_ADS
                            [5] => BASIC_ADMIN
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [category] => App Page
                    [name] => StarPeak - Money Through Glory
                    [id] => 33953467150574
                    [perms] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => ADMINISTER
                            [1] => EDIT_PROFILE
                            [2] => CREATE_CONTENT
                            [3] => MODERATE_CONTENT
                            [4] => CREATE_ADS
                            [5] => BASIC_ADMIN
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [category] => Real Estate
                    [category_list] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 198327773511962
                                    [name] => Real Estate
                                )

                        )

                    [name] => TezTap.az - AxtardÄ±ÄŸÄ±nÄ± tez tap
                    [id] => 14443736253434587
                    [perms] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => ADMINISTER
                            [1] => EDIT_PROFILE
                            [2] => CREATE_CONTENT
                            [3] => MODERATE_CONTENT
                            [4] => CREATE_ADS
                            [5] => BASIC_ADMIN
                        )

                )

    [paging] => Array
        (
            [cursors] => Array
                (
                    [before] => Mjc5MTMwODY1OTКХNTk4
                    [after] => MTUyODUКХzg4MDcwMzE0MQZDZD
                )

        )

)
```

как вывести только [name] из этого массива?

Сделал так не помогло

```
foreach( $data2 as $value ) {
        echo $value->name;
}
```

Comment: `foreach( $data2['data'] as $value ){ echo $value['name'];}`

Comment: прочитайте про рекурсию.

Comment: @And а зачем тут рекурсия?

Comment: @rjhdby в целом поймет, работу массивов или объектов, так-как ему, все-же, захотелось написать так: `->`.

Comment: @rjhdby  Спасибо сработало.

Answer (score 3):

1. У вас вложенный массив. Вам надо перебирать не `$data2`, а `$data2['data']`
2. У вас массив, а не объект. Доступ к элементу `name` должен быть такой `$value['name']`

Т.е.:

```
foreach( $data2['data'] as $value ){ 
    echo $value['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Из-за того, что массив многомерный, а искомые элементы `'name'` находятся на разных уровнях, нужно пользоваться рекурсивной функцией. Можно встроенной [array_walk_recursive()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-walk-recursive.php):

> Массив

```
$data2 = Array(
    'data' => Array(
        Array(
            'category'=> 'Website',
            'name'    => 'Brains',
            'id'      => 2791308653434598,
            'perms'    => Array(
                ADMINISTER,
                EDIT_PROFILE,
                CREATE_CONTENT,
                MODERATE_CONTENT,
                CREATE_ADS,
                BASIC_ADMIN
            )
        ),

        Array(
            'category'=> 'App Page',
            'name'    => 'StarPeak - Money Through Glory',
            'id'      => 33953467150574,
            'perms'   => Array(
                ADMINISTER,
                EDIT_PROFILE,
                CREATE_CONTENT,
                MODERATE_CONTENT,
                CREATE_ADS,
                BASIC_ADMIN
            )

        ),

        Array(
            'category'     => 'Real Estate',
            'category_list' => Array(
                Array(
                    'id'  => 198327773511962,
                    'name'=> 'Real Estate'
                )
            ),
            'name' => 'TezTap.az - AxtardÄ±ÄŸÄ±nÄ± tez tap',
            'id' => 14443736253434587,
            'perms' => Array(
                ADMINISTER,
                EDIT_PROFILE,
                CREATE_CONTENT,
                MODERATE_CONTENT,
                CREATE_ADS,
                BASIC_ADMIN
            )

        ),

        'paging' => Array(
            'cursors' => Array(
                'before'=> 'Mjc5MTMwODY1OTКХNTk4',
                'after' => 'MTUyODUКХzg4MDcwMzE0MQZDZD'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

> **Код**

```
array_walk_recursive($data2, function($v, $k) {
    echo (!empty($k) && $k == 'name') ? "$v<br>" : '';
});
```

> Результат

```
Brains
StarPeak - Money Through Glory
Real Estate
TezTap.az - AxtardÄ±ÄŸÄ±nÄ± tez tap
```

Comment: @УзеирЗейналзаде вам не обойтись простым циклом.